# Дублируется код на странице при использовании ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Скажите, пожалуйста, почему, когда я использую ajax запрос для вывода данных из бд у меня дублируется код на странице?
Есть input в который я вношу название для поиска данных и получаю результат из БД, результат выводиться правильно, но вместе с ним и дублируется код половины страницы.

```js
$(document).ready(()=>{
    $('#code').bind('input', function(){
            console.log($(this).val());
            $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: '/include/db.php',
            method: 'post',
            dataType:"text",
            data: {
                code: $(this).val(),
            },
            success: function (data){
                  $('#search__items2').html(data);
            },
            error: (e)=>{
              console.log(e.responseText);
              $('body').append(e.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```js
<div class="cart">
<div class="cards cards--list">

<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>C:\Users\aquil\Desktop\OpenServer\domains\LUX\resources\inc\inc_cart\inc_cart.php</b> on line <b>62</b><br />
<!-- .card AJAX -->
</div><!-- .cards -->
</div><!-- .cart -->

<div class="cart-total">
  <p class="cart-total__number"> товара(ов) на сумму:</p>
  <p class="cart-total__amount"> ₽</p>
  <p class="cart-total__text">Есть промокод?</p>
    <form>
      <div id="search__items2">
                <span>test</span>
              </div>
      <input class="cart-total__promocode" id="code" name="code" type="text" placeholder="Впишите его в это поле" />
    </form>
    <button class="cart-total__check" id="btn-code" name="btn-code" type="button">Проверить</button>
  <button class="cart-total__order" type="button">Офорить заказ</button>
</div><!-- .cart-total -->
<script>
$(document).ready(()=>{
    $('#code').bind('input', function(){
            console.log($(this).val());
            $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: '/resources/inc/inc_cart/inc_cart',
            method: 'post',
            dataType:"text",
            data: {
                code: $(this).val(),
            },
            success: function (data){
                  console.log(data);
                  $('#search__items2').html($(data).find('#search__items2').html());
            },
            error: (e)=>{
              console.log(e.responseText);
              $('body').append(e.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: что значит "дублируется код половины страницы? какой страницы?

Comment: мне кажется, вместо append лучше использоваться text и туда вставлять данные, для большей безопасности

Comment: Вам надо распознавать результат запроса используя [DomParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) и извлекать данные используя jQuery или ему подобные. Если вы напишете о проблеме подробнее, может быть, вам напишут конкретный код.

Comment: @ThisMan скриншот -> https://yadi.sk/i/tUcnYk8Md4RKpA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#search__items2').html($(data).find('#search__items2').html());
```

Comment: код не дублируется, но и результат из бд тоже не отображается.

Comment: @hellokitViki Где на Вашей картинке "результат из бд"?

Comment: в самом низу, под дублированной формой написано test

Comment: @hellokitViki Какой это элемент в `data`?

Comment: input, если я прввильно поняла вопрос

Comment: @hellokitViki Не совсем :). Покажите кусок html из ответа `data`на ajax-запрос, в котором содержится то, что Вы хотите добавить в `#search__items2`.

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/jOCZjkAwHeRVdQ

Comment: @hellokitViki Перенесите цикл `foreach` внутрь `<div id="search__items2">`.

Comment: неа, уже пыталась так. Мне кажется это из-за того что на странице корзины уже используется ajax для вывода товаров и как-то скрипты между собой не ладят.

Comment: @hellokitViki Не "неа", а перенесите и используйте код из ответа. Скрипты не могут "не ладить" - у них ручек и ножек нету.

Comment: так я и говорю, что это не работает всё равно

Comment: @hellokitViki Вы неаккуратно скопировали к себе мой код.

Comment: разобралась, почистила кэш и сервер перезапустила, какой-то баг. Теперь Ваш код работает)

Comment: @hellokitViki Добавьте в `success` первой строчкой `console.log(data);`, то, что выведется в консоль браузера, включите в вопрос. Только текстом, а не картинкой.

Comment: добавила, как вы сказали

Comment: @hellokitViki Спасибо. Как и ожидалось, `<span>test</span>` присутствует внутри `<div id="search__items2">`.